# How to redirect port 80 on server A to 443 server B

Tags: redirects, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-proxy

I'm wondering how can use my server A to redirect different URL's to the respective server. 
Here is my setup:

Server A: apache 2.4 on ubuntu 16
Server B: apache 2.4 on windows 2012

Port 80 is forwarded to server A on the firewall. 
Let's say I want URL http://hr.xyz.com forwarded to http**s**://hr.xyz.com on server B, how can I achieve this (notice change from port 80 to 443)?

I've been trying with ProxyPass & RewriteEngine (seperately, not at the same time) in my 
000-default.conf but haven't had any success

ProxyPass 
Server A:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName hr.xyz.com
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / https://ip.from.server.B:443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://ip.from.server.B:443/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

RewriteEngine:
Server A

```
On server A
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName hr.xyz.be


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://hr.xyz.com/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Server B:

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^hr.xyz.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://hr.xyz.com/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

But I guess RewriteEngine is only meant to be configured on the same Apache server, not 2 as is my case.

Could someone advice me how to succeed please?

Comment: You might need to rewrite with a reverse proxy: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html

Comment: "But I guess RewriteEngine is only meant to be configured on the same Apache server" - what do you mean by this? What is happening? What is the desired result? By "forwarding to https://...", are you wanting to send the response back over the original insecure HTTP connection? As opposed to an actual redirect? You can use mod_rewrite with mod_proxy as well, however, in your example you are issuing an external redirect.

Comment: @DocRoot: I mean that I think you can only use the RewriteEngine and the rules for http -> https only on the same server, not on 2 separate servers as in my case. The desired result is that people are redirected from http://hr.xyz.com to https://hr.xyz.com. The problem is, there is another site (with different url) on port 80 which still needs to be available.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's physically one server or two. mod_rewrite is not aware of this. What matters is where `https://hr.xyz.com/` resolves to. So, it is an _external redirect_ that you require? ie. the _user_ is physically redirected from `http://hr.xyz.com` to `https://hr.xyz.com`? However, your use of the terms "forwarded" and "proxy" suggest otherwise? What do you want the user to see in the browsers address bar?

Comment: I'm still learning apache so excuse me if I misuse some terms like forward & proxy. What you describe is exactly what I want: the user types 'http://hr.xyz.com' which is then redirected to 'https://hr.xyz.com' (which is also the address in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this on a much simpler way than my initial thoughts. I've only used server B for this setup.

As described in the [apache documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL), one can use `redirect`.

I added an extra virtualhost in de httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName hr.xyz.com
            Redirect 301 / https://hr.xyz.com
```

This results in redirecting the url `http://hr.xyz.com` to `https://hr.xyz.com` which is exactly what I wanted!